# How to add an event to svg graphics object using external script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I am displaying a webpage within my own webpage using an iframe.
The webpage displays a graph with svg graphics, specifically circles.
(the internal webpage is a kibana dashboard that displays a graph)
This means that I am unable to change the html inside of the page but I have found a way to add javascript to elements within the iframe.

Some existing behavior: When you hover the mouse over the circle a box with information appears which tells me that it is possible to have a jquery event triggered from the graphic element.

Using the developer tools I found the alleged function that causes this effect but it is part of a much larger function that tosses references around like willy-nilly. I believe that there is a much cleaner way to accomplish my goals

I want to perform my own event lets say console.log

Once again, I suppressed the same origin policy for testing and I have verified that I can create events for elements inside.

However I am having difficulty accessing svg elements. The circles which I am trying to reach do not have id’s and I don’t know of a way to select by the type of graphic it is.

Typical solutions for adding javascript events use id's to select specific svg graphic objects or add a script within svg tags. This is not possible as I cannot alter the existing svg code.

Could you please offer me a solution in which a script outside of the svg tags is able to access each of the circle objects and associate onclick events? Bonus points if I can target the circles with radiuses of 12 and exclude those with radiuses of 2.

The html (which I am unable to change) with two encapsulating div's is as follows. Most of it is identical circles.

```
    <div class="chart-wrapper">
                <div class="chart">
                <svg width="1564" height="542">
                <g transform="translate(3,10)" clip-path="url(#chart-area266)">
                <clipPath id="chart-area266">
                <rect x="0" y="-5" width="1558" height="532">
                </rect>
                </clipPath>
                <g class="endzone">
        <rect class="zone" x="0" y="0" height="527" width="0">
        </rect>
            </g>
                <g class="endzone">
                <rect class="zone" x="1564.000018101852" y="0" height="527" width="0">
    </rect>
            </g>
                <g class="brush" style="pointer-events: all; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">
                <rect class="background" x="0" width="1564" height="527" style="visibility: hidden; cursor: crosshair;">
                </rect>
                <rect class="extent" x="0" width="0" height="527" style="cursor: move;">
                </rect>
                <g class="resize e" transform="translate(0,0)" style="cursor: ew-resize; display: none;">
                <rect x="-3" width="6" height="527" style="visibility: hidden;">
                </rect>
                </g>
                <g class="resize w" transform="translate(0,0)" style="cursor: ew-resize; display: none;">
                <rect x="-3" width="6" height="527" style="visibility: hidden;">
                </rect>
                </g>
                </g>
                <g class="pathgroup lines">
                <path data-label="Average cpu.aggregate.usage.combined.mean" d="M415.20125273148153,28.848655980888704L447.78458606481485,77.16452456458111L480.3679193981481,106.26861258939131L512.9512527314815,134.37276407340656L545.5345860648148,103.52098335395252L578.1179193981482,119.11166363835777L610.7012527314815,115.72535246100395L643.2845860648148,144.13977822327658L675.8679193981482,123.70661263454268L708.4512527314815,133.7553271326282L741.0345860648148,115.09513480938388L773.6179193981482,143.22639873640802L806.2012527314815,137.44737329744905L838.7845860648148,120.62507507387792L871.3679193981482,135.91311169794196L903.9512527314815,128.89312516934314L936.5345860648148,138.9573662073501L969.1179193981482,141.99999213078416L1001.7012527314815,122.47023931436064L1034.2845860648147,146.002943798389L1066.8679193981482,153.32655767373876L1099.4512527314814,148.8908469068648" fill="none" stroke="#57c17b" stroke-width="2">
                </path>
                </g>
                <g class="points line">
                <circle r="2" fill-opacity="1" cx="415.20125273148153" cy="28.848655980888704" fill="#57c17b" class="circle-decoration" data-label="Average cpu.aggregate.usage.combined.mean">
                </circle>
                <circle r="2" fill-opacity="1" cx="447.78458606481485" cy="77.16452456458111" fill="#57c17b" class="circle-decoration" data-label="Average cpu.aggregate.usage.combined.mean">
                </circle>
                <circle r="2" fill-opacity="1" cx="480.3679193981481" cy="106.26861258939131" fill="#57c17b" class="circle-decoration" data-label="Average cpu.aggregate.usage.combined.mean">
        </circle>
        <circle r="2" fill-opacity="1" cx="512.9512527314815" cy="134.37276407340656" fill="#57c17b" class="circle-decoration" data-label="Average cpu.aggregate.usage.combined.mean">
                </circle>
        <circle r="2" fill-opacity="1" cx="545.5345860648148" cy="103.52098335395252" fill="#57c17b" class="circle-decoration" data-label="Average cpu.aggregate.usage.combined.mean">
                </circle>
                <circle r="2" fill-opacity="1" cx="578.1179193981482" cy="119.11166363835777" fill="#57c17b" class="circle-decoration" data-label="Average cpu.aggregate.usage.combined.mean">
                </circle>
                <circle r="2" fill-opacity="1" cx="610.7012527314815" cy="115.72535246100395" fill="#57c17b" class="circle-decoration" data-label="Average cpu.aggregate.usage.combined.mean">
                </circle>
        <circle r="2" fill-opacity="1" cx="643.2845860648148" cy="144.13977822327658" fill="#57c17b" class="circle-decoration" data-label="Average cpu.aggregate.usage.combined.mean">
            </circle>
        <circle r="2" fill-opacity="1" cx="675.8679193981482" cy="123.70661263454268" fill="#57c17b" class="circle-decoration" data-label="Average cpu.aggregate.usage.combined.mean">
                </circle>
        <circle r="2" fill-opacity="1" cx="708.4512527314815" cy="133.7553271326282" fill="#57c17b" class="circle-decoration" data-label="Average cpu.aggregate.usage.combined.mean">
        </circle>
        <circle r="2" fill-opacity="1" cx="741.0345860648148" cy="115.09513480938388" fill="#57c17b" class="circle-decoration" data-label="Average cpu.aggregate.usage.combined.mean">
                </circle>
            <circle r="2" fill-opacity="1" cx="773.6179193981482" cy="143.22639873640802" fill="#57c17b" class="circle-decoration" data-label="Average cpu.aggregate.usage.combined.mean">
                </circle>
            <circle r="2" fill-opacity="1" cx="806.2012527314815" cy="137.44737329744905" fill="#57c17b" class="circle-decoration" data-label="Average cpu.aggregate.usage.combined.mean">
            </circle>
            <circle r="2" fill-opacity="1" cx="838.7845860648148" cy="120.62507507387792" fill="#57c17b" class="circle-decoration" data-label="Average cpu.aggregate.usage.combined.mean">
                </circle>
            <circle r="2" fill-opacity="1" cx="871.3679193981482" cy="135.91311169794196" fill="#57c17b" class="circle-decoration" data-label="Average cpu.aggregate.usage.combined.mean">
        </circle>
        <circle r="2" fill-opacity="1" cx="903.9512527314815" cy="128.89312516934314" fill="#57c17b" class="circle-decoration" data-label="Average cpu.aggregate.usage.combined.mean">
        </circle>
        <circle r="2" fill-opacity="1" cx="936.5345860648148" cy="138.9573662073501" fill="#57c17b" class="circle-decoration" data-label="Average cpu.aggregate.usage.combined.mean">
    </circle>
<circle r="2" fill-opacity="1" cx="969.1179193981482" cy="141.99999213078416" fill="#57c17b" class="circle-decoration" data-label="Average cpu.aggregate.usage.combined.mean">
            </circle>
    <circle r="2" fill-opacity="1" cx="1001.7012527314815" cy="122.47023931436064" fill="#57c17b" class="circle-decoration" data-label="Average cpu.aggregate.usage.combined.mean">
            </circle>
    <circle r="2" fill-opacity="1" cx="1034.2845860648147" cy="146.002943798389" fill="#57c17b" class="circle-decoration" data-label="Average cpu.aggregate.usage.combined.mean">
            </circle>
            <circle r="2" fill-opacity="1" cx="1066.8679193981482" cy="153.32655767373876" fill="#57c17b" class="circle-decoration" data-label="Average cpu.aggregate.usage.combined.mean">
            </circle>
            <circle r="2" fill-opacity="1" cx="1099.4512527314814" cy="148.8908469068648" fill="#57c17b" class="circle-decoration" data-label="Average cpu.aggregate.usage.combined.mean">
    </circle>
    <circle r="12" cx="415.20125273148153" cy="28.848655980888704" fill="transparent" class="circle" data-label="Average cpu.aggregate.usage.combined.mean" stroke="#57c17b" stroke-width="0" style="cursor: pointer;">
            </circle>
            <circle r="12" cx="447.78458606481485" cy="77.16452456458111" fill="transparent" class="circle" data-label="Average cpu.aggregate.usage.combined.mean" stroke="#57c17b" stroke-width="0" style="cursor: pointer;">
    </circle>
    <circle r="12" cx="480.3679193981481" cy="106.26861258939131" fill="transparent" class="circle" data-label="Average cpu.aggregate.usage.combined.mean" stroke="#57c17b" stroke-width="0" style="cursor: pointer;">
    </circle>
    <circle r="12" cx="512.9512527314815" cy="134.37276407340656" fill="transparent" class="circle" data-label="Average cpu.aggregate.usage.combined.mean" stroke="#57c17b" stroke-width="0" style="cursor: pointer;">
    </circle>
    <circle r="12" cx="545.5345860648148" cy="103.52098335395252" fill="transparent" class="circle" data-label="Average cpu.aggregate.usage.combined.mean" stroke="#57c17b" stroke-width="0" style="cursor: pointer;">
    </circle>
    <circle r="12" cx="578.1179193981482" cy="119.11166363835777" fill="transparent" class="circle" data-label="Average cpu.aggregate.usage.combined.mean" stroke="#57c17b" stroke-width="0" style="cursor: pointer;">
            </circle>
            <circle r="12" cx="610.7012527314815" cy="115.72535246100395" fill="transparent" class="circle" data-label="Average cpu.aggregate.usage.combined.mean" stroke="#57c17b" stroke-width="0" style="cursor: pointer;">
            </circle>
    <circle r="12" cx="643.2845860648148" cy="144.13977822327658" fill="transparent" class="circle" data-label="Average cpu.aggregate.usage.combined.mean" stroke="#57c17b" stroke-width="0">
            </circle>
    <circle r="12" cx="675.8679193981482" cy="123.70661263454268" fill="transparent" class="circle" data-label="Average cpu.aggregate.usage.combined.mean" stroke="#57c17b" stroke-width="0">
            </circle>
    <circle r="12" cx="708.4512527314815" cy="133.7553271326282" fill="transparent" class="circle" data-label="Average cpu.aggregate.usage.combined.mean" stroke="#57c17b" stroke-width="0">
            </circle>
            <circle r="12" cx="741.0345860648148" cy="115.09513480938388" fill="transparent" class="circle" data-label="Average cpu.aggregate.usage.combined.mean" stroke="#57c17b" stroke-width="0">
            </circle>
            <circle r="12" cx="773.6179193981482" cy="143.22639873640802" fill="transparent" class="circle" data-label="Average cpu.aggregate.usage.combined.mean" stroke="#57c17b" stroke-width="0" style="cursor: pointer;">
            </circle>
            <circle r="12" cx="806.2012527314815" cy="137.44737329744905" fill="transparent" class="circle" data-label="Average cpu.aggregate.usage.combined.mean" stroke="#57c17b" stroke-width="0" style="cursor: pointer;">
            </circle>
            <circle r="12" cx="838.7845860648148" cy="120.62507507387792" fill="transparent" class="circle" data-label="Average cpu.aggregate.usage.combined.mean" stroke="#57c17b" stroke-width="0" style="cursor: pointer;">
            </circle>
            <circle r="12" cx="871.3679193981482" cy="135.91311169794196" fill="transparent" class="circle" data-label="Average cpu.aggregate.usage.combined.mean" stroke="#57c17b" stroke-width="0">
            </circle>
            <circle r="12" cx="903.9512527314815" cy="128.89312516934314" fill="transparent" class="circle" data-label="Average cpu.aggregate.usage.combined.mean" stroke="#57c17b" stroke-width="0">
            </circle>
<circle r="12" cx="936.5345860648148" cy="138.9573662073501" fill="transparent" class="circle" data-label="Average cpu.aggregate.usage.combined.mean" stroke="#57c17b" stroke-width="0">
    </circle>
<circle r="12" cx="969.1179193981482" cy="141.99999213078416" fill="transparent" class="circle" data-label="Average cpu.aggregate.usage.combined.mean" stroke="#57c17b" stroke-width="0">
            </circle>
            <circle r="12" cx="1001.7012527314815" cy="122.47023931436064" fill="transparent" class="circle" data-label="Average cpu.aggregate.usage.combined.mean" stroke="#57c17b" stroke-width="0">
            </circle>
            <circle r="12" cx="1034.2845860648147" cy="146.002943798389" fill="transparent" class="circle" data-label="Average cpu.aggregate.usage.combined.mean" stroke="#57c17b" stroke-width="0">
            </circle>
            <circle r="12" cx="1066.8679193981482" cy="153.32655767373876" fill="transparent" class="circle" data-label="Average cpu.aggregate.usage.combined.mean" stroke="#57c17b" stroke-width="0">
    </circle>
<circle r="12" cx="1099.4512527314814" cy="148.8908469068648" fill="transparent" class="circle" data-label="Average cpu.aggregate.usage.combined.mean" stroke="#57c17b" stroke-width="0">
            </circle>
            </g>
            <line class="base-line" x1="0" y1="527" x2="1558" y2="527" style="stroke: rgb(221, 221, 221); stroke-width: 1px;">
            </line>
            </g>
            </svg>
                </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: call getElementsByTagName and then work on only elements with the r attribute that you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just get the elements you want and then loop over them to attach click handlers. See: http://jsbin.com/lehido/edit?html,js,console,output

Of course this is very simple example, you should filter the elements you want to operate on beforehand in case you would need them later, but I'm sure you can work it out no your own.

If you want to have nice API and already have jQuery included, there is jquery.svg which is modular and easy to use. http://keith-wood.name/svg.html